# Pygame Key events only detects a limited amount of keys being held down

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

Hi I have used pygame (the modules for python) for a while. Now I have written a RPG game that has multiple keys been held down at once. It seem that only 2 or 3 keys are detected whiles been held down. If anyone knows how to fix this problem it would be great. Try out my code below for python 2.7 and see if you have the same problem.  Thanks

```
import pygame

def main():
    # Initialise screen
    pygame.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((150, 50))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Basic Pygame program')

    # Fill background
    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background = background.convert()
    background.fill((250, 250, 250))

    # Display some text
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
    text = font.render("Hello There", 1, (10, 10, 10))
    textpos = text.get_rect()
    textpos.centerx = background.get_rect().centerx
    background.blit(text, textpos)

    # Blit everything to the screen
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    q=0
    w=0
    e=0
    r=0

    #Event loop
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q  : 
                q = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_w  : 
                w = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_e  : 
                e = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_r  : 
                r = 1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q  : 
                q = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_w  : 
                w = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_e  : 
                e = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_r  : 
                r = 0
        count = q+w+e+r
        print("Total: "+str(count)+"  q: "+str(q) + "   w: "+str(w)+ "   e: "+str(e)+ "   r: "+str(r))
        clock.tick(30)
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()
if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Here I have tryed with pygame.key.get_pressed() but it still does not seem to work with more than 3 keys being held down. )-:

```
from pygame.locals import * 
import pygame
def main():
    # Initialise screen
    pygame.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((150, 50))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Basic Pygame program')

    # Fill background
    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background = background.convert()
    background.fill((250, 250, 250))

    # Display some text
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
    text = font.render("Hello There", 1, (10, 10, 10))
    textpos = text.get_rect()
    textpos.centerx = background.get_rect().centerx
    background.blit(text, textpos)

    # Blit everything to the screen
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()


    #Event loop
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return
        q=0
        w=0
        e=0
        r=0
        keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_q]  : 
            q = 1
        if keys[K_w]  : 
            w = 1
        if keys[K_e]  : 
            e = 1
        if keys[K_r]  : 
            r = 1

        count = q+w+e+r
        print("Total: "+str(count)+"  q: "+str(q) + "   w: "+str(w)+ "   e: "+str(e)+ "   r: "+str(r))
        clock.tick(30)
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__': main(
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite likely this is [a hardware issue with your keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29), not something you can address in your game's software. Most keyboards have a limit on the number of keys they can read as being pressed simultaneously (though common modifier keys like Shift and Control are usually handled separately). It's not at all uncommon on laptop or lower-end desktop keyboards for only two ordinary (non modifier) key presses to be supported at a time. Gaming keyboards (and higher-end keyboards in general) will support more, but there's often still some limit. If you press more keys than the keyboard can handle, it will either ignore the later presses (known as "jamming") or cause the keyboard to report extra key presses for other keys (known as "ghosting").

If you're designing a game yourself, this is probably an important thing to be aware of, since it will affect your players, not just you! You probably want to make sure you don't design your game's interface in such a way that users of low-end keyboards can't play effectively. If your UI cannot possibly work without multiple keys being pressed at once, you might want to move some of the key assignments to modifier keys like Shift and Control, which have a better chance of being supported when being pressed at the same time as other keys. With the prevalence of first-person shooter games, the WASD keys may also get special handling on some keyboards.

Comment: This seems to be the case. I had only run the game on both my laptop and a few other older computers. As soon as I tried my gaming Keyboard, it worked perfectly. If you know of any way to get around this (i.e. allowing older keyboards to get more inputs) that would be great. Thanks (-:

Comment: I doubt there is a direct workaround for an older keyboard, since the issue has to do with its internal design. If your game supports key remapping, your users might be able to work around some issues by rebinding certain actions to modifier keys that might have fewer conflicts, but that's probably the most you can do (other than modifying the game design so that you don't need as many simultaneous key presses).

Answer (score 0):

You can used 'get_pressed' which will give you a bool value for every key on the keyboard.

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_LEFT]:
        go_left()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but this seems that this still only detects 2 or 3 keys being held down